# VBA : .Find with error "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Tags: excel, object, set, block, vba

This is my first post - although I have been lurking in the overflow for a little while now. I am reasonably new to VBA and I have learnt so much from this forum so thank you all.

The code I have takes a string, opens another excel file and attempts to search for the string in the first column of the opened file. I am receiving the error:

"vba error: object variable or with block variable not set" on the .find I believe. Your help would be very much appreciated. I have tried various things but to be honest I feel like I am battling in the dark.

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub GetProductCode()
'Opens jobs file
'Trims down customer reference column to job number only, then searches job file to return product code
Dim sJobNumber As String
Dim sCustomerReference As String
Dim rownum As Long
Dim wbkJobs As Workbook
Dim wsJobs As Worksheet
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim strSearch As String
Dim x As Range

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change as desired
    strPathFile = "\\ACHILLES\Company\Production_schedule\Jobs.xlsm"
    strSearch = "Specific text"

 Set wbkJobs = Workbooks.Open _
              (Filename:=strPathFile, _
              UpdateLinks:=0, _
              ReadOnly:=True, _
              AddToMRU:=False)

'MsgBox wbkJobs.Name


rownum = 2
'Refer to sheet using code name (3)
sCustomerReference = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("E" & rownum).Value
'MsgBox sCustomerReference
sJobNumber = Right(sCustomerReference, 5)
'MsgBox sJobNumber
strSearch = ("*" & sJobNumber)
'MsgBox strSearch
Set wsJobs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Jobs")

Set x = wsJobs.Range("A:A").Find(What:=strSearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

Comment: Can you comment the line `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` and then run the code. It will point to the exact line which is giving the error. I suspect you are getting the error at a line which is not shown in the above code. You must have directly tried to work with `X` range without even checking if `If X is Not Nothing`

Comment: Siddharth Rout, you are amazing. Thank you sooo much! The next line of code is a simple "msgbox x". I have added "if not x = nothing" and it now runs!!! Thank you thank you thank you. Simple and silly mistake :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)